# I want to conect a slider with different columns of data in CartoDB

Tags: carto

I am writing a map with CartoDB, and I would like to connect a slider with a select layer.
It is a slider of four points (2010-2011-2012-2013).
I want to connect the result of slider with the correspond column of database: data_2010; data_2011; data_2012 and data_2013
I am not sure if there is a function to do this, or if I have to use different layers in CartoDB, one to each data column.
This is the code:

Time Slider | CartoDB.js
    
    
    
    
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #slider-range-max {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 40px;
        right: 850px;
        left:110px;
      }

```
  #legend {
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 27px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  #legend2 {
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 27px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 100px;
  }
```

}

```
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

$(function() {
    $('#legend').html("Chile - Years")
    $('#legend2').html("" + 2010 + "     ---     " + 2011 + "     ---     " + 2012 + "     ---     " + 2013)
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 2010,
    max: 2013,
    value: 2010,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
    }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });

```
<!-- include cartodb.js library -->
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.11/cartodb.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  function main() {
    var map = new L.Map('map', {
      center: [-39.66841891894786, -60.96533203125],
      zoom: 4
    });

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.api.cartocdn.com/base-light/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'CartoDB · Juan Moises de la Serna'
    }).addTo(map);

    cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://juanmoises.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/84a61b7e-b39c-11e4-bb07-0e853d047bba/viz.json', { legends: true })
     .addTo(map)
     .on('done', function(layer) {
    }).on('error', function() {
      cartodb.log.log("some error occurred");
    });
  }

  // you could use $(window).load(main);
  window.onload = main;
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange :)  I think the code formatting is messed up. When in edit mode select the code text and use `Ctrl-K` to indent (and keep an eye on preview to see if results are correct).

Answer (score 1):

The related example is [this link](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/tree/develop/examples/slider)

Basically, the main idea uses the following code with createLayers.

```
    if (container === "before") {
        cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/0b6b2f94-6a52-11e4-8910-0e853d047bba/viz.json')
        .addTo(map)
        .done(function(layer) {
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            console.log("error layer before : " + err);
        });

    } else {
        cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/bdeb4618-6a52-11e4-8522-0e9d821ea90d/viz.json')
        .addTo(map)
        .done(function(layer) {

        })
        .error(function(err) {
            console.log("error layer after: " + err);
        });
    }
```